# How to delete specific cells in a column (with shift cells left) option in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have my input data is as follows.

Input

```
        10-08-2012      15-08-2012      
sid abc001  0   abc001  0   abc001  
status  p   0   p   0   s   
intime  10:00   0   10:00   0   09:00   
outtime 19:00   0   19:00   0   18:00   
Total   9   0   9   0   9
```

Here I need to delete specific cells in a column by shifting besides cells data to the left side. I have gone through below code to get required output.

```
Sub Delete_Range_To_ShiftLeft()

    Range("C3:C7").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Required output:

```
        10-08-2012  15-08-2012          
sid abc001  abc001  abc001          
status  p   p   s           
intime  10:00   10:00   09:00           
outtime 19:00   19:00   18:00           
Total   9   9   9
```

Can you please let me know, if you have any better way to do it?

Comment: So loop through the columns and delete every other one.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  Please attempt on your own and come back when you have code that is not working.

Comment: Hi scott ,I have tried my own I got it with below code  ...                                                                                      Sub Delete_Range_To_ShiftLeft()
Range("D2:D7").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub "is there any better way to do it, can you  please share with me .

Comment: Please use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39491312/edit) to put the code in your original post not in the comments.